# Evaluation metrics for out-of-fold predictions obtained through negative binomial regression

Tags: regression, predictive-models, model-evaluation, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm formulating count data out-of-fold predictions using a negative binomial regression and i am a bit confused as to which evaluation metrics apply best. My dependent variable has a long tail distribution, so i was thinking of using RMLSE and MAE. Is this correct?

What other evaluation metrics can be used in this context?

Comment: Do you mean that you do not think your response variable is conditionally negative binomial?

Comment: @Dave apologies, i made a mistake there. I meant dependent variable. I have edited the question. My y is not normally distributed. My, frankly quite poor, understanding of RMSLE is that it is more appropriate in such circumstance than RMSE, which is more favourable when the distribution of y is normal.